# ActiveX WebBrowser control do not load countries dictionary on web-form

Tags: c++, webbrowser-control, atl

Good day!

First of all I want to say sorry for my pure English :)

I need to host an ActiveX WebBrowser control object on one of the forms of my application. I use ATL CAxWindow::Create(... CLSID_WebBrowser ...) and at first sight all is OK: web sites load correctly, navigating works, no any problems.
But one of the web-forms contains a list-box with countries dictionary to load from server and my WebBrowser control do not load it, therefore I cannot fill this web-form fully..

If I navigate to that web-form with IE the country dictionary loads correctly. I have several samples/examples of WebBrowser control applications (with MFC CWnd::CreateControl and other) and some of them DO NOT WORK like my application, but some - WORK CORRECTLY. I do not see any serious differences between my app and downloaded samples yet, so I need help.

P. S. I tried to change FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION for my application in registry (IE 7.0, IE 8.0, IE 9.0 modes), but without effect. Though, samples work without any registry tweaks.

Comment: There are [more features](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee330733(v=vs.85).aspx) out there, try setting all of them to the corresponding IE default values (the docs specify which value is the default for IE).

Comment: Thansk for your answer. I've already read this registry keys and have no idea. Samples/examples work without any registry tweaks and I suppose so my application must work with default registry keys.

Comment: Have you tried all of them? My point was, they have different default values between full IE and `WebBrowser` control.

Comment: Now, a haven't tried all of them, but after you comment I'm in process. Is the flags (WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_CLIPCHILDREN etc..) the same with registry keys? Perhaps, my flags in CAxWindow::Create() crash WebBrowser control functionality?

Comment: The flags look OK to me, I don't think they could cause what you described. If you get there with any combination of the features, let us know what helped. BTW, does the site work OK in full IE browser?

Comment: Yes, in full IE browser and in SOME sample WebBrowser control applications the site works OK. Surely, I let you know what helped in my case.

Comment: I added MessageBox'es to OnDownloadBegin and OnDownloadComplete handlers in my app and in working sample application. When I type a first letter in edit-control (for example, I type 'G' to choose "Germany" from loaded dictionary), the OnDownloadBegin event rises in case of working sample. My application do not rise OnDownloadBegin event when I type a letter in edit control...

Comment: What about other `DWebBrowserEvents2` events, are you getting any at all?

Comment: @Noseratio, I've added debugging events log and have had 2 experiments. On every letter typeing on web-form's edit control there are next events: OnBeforeNavigate2, OnDownloadBegin, OnNavigateComplete2, OnProgressChange, OnDownloadComplete, OnDocumentComplete. This is result of working sample app. My application do not rises any events on typeing in edit control.

Comment: I have a simple test app using hosting `WebBrowser` ActiveX control with ATL [here](http://goo.gl/XFuhUk). This is probably as much as I can help with your case.

Comment: @Noseratio, your test app doesn't load dictionary too. One detail: I use my own UIHandler and set it by CAxWindow::SetExternalUIHandler(). Can my handler be a reason of problem?

Comment: Could really be anything, I can't help without being able to repro. If you have a sample that works, try to spot the difference between its code and yours.

Answer (score 0):

I will try to remember how the problem was solved:

There are no miracles and WebBrowser contol object didn't work because of custom windows messages (WM_KEYDOWN, WM_KEYUP, etc) handler in host application. One simple experiment showed me that the control itself worked correctly and I started to study the host application code, where custom WM-hadlers were found.